# Python3 requests module PUT empty file

Tags: python-3.x, azure, python-requests, azure-rest-api

Using the Python3 requests module and the [PUT Blob Azure Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-blob) to upload a file into Azure storage:

```
file_name = "testfile.txt"
url = f"https://<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net/test/{file_name}?sv=<SASTOKEN>"
with open(file_name, 'rb') as data:
    headers = {
        'x-ms-version': '2019-02-02',
        'x-ms-date': 'Mon, 30 Mar 2020 17:20:00 GMT',
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        'x-ms-access-tier': 'Cool'
    }

    response = requests.put(
        url, 
        data=data,
        headers=headers
    )
    print(f"Response {response}")
```

This works for files with content. But, when trying to upload an empty file I get a `400` response code. How can I upload an empty file?

Comment: Please add the completed code.

Comment: Updated with the missing variables

Comment: See answer below if uploading an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload an empty file, you should remove the `data=data` in the `requests.put()` method.

```
print("**begin**")
with open(file_name,'rb') as data:
    headers = {
        'x-ms-version': '2019-02-02',
        'x-ms-date': 'Fri, 03 Apr 2020 07:16:17 GMT',
        'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob',
        'x-ms-access-tier': 'Cool'
    }

    response = requests.put(
        url, 
        headers=headers
    )
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.content)

print("**done**")
```

And also, you can conditionally use `requests.put()` method with/without `data=data`. First, in your code, check the length of the file, if it's zero, you can use `requests.put()` method without `data=data`; and if the length is larger than zero, use the `requests.put()` method with `data=data`.

Hope it can helps.